# How do I import an Excel file to Pandas if the file's last modified date is today?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I'm trying to write a Python script that imports an excel file into a Pandas dataframe (condition being if the file was modified on a certain date, ex. today):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import datetime

def report():
    for x in glob.glob("../*.xlsx"):
        modx = os.path.getmtime(x)
        xmod = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modx)
    if datetime.datetime.today() == xmod:
        return x
```

I've considered importing the excel file right from the function:

```
if datetime.datetime.today() == xmod:
    df = pd.read_excel(x)
    return df
```

An attempt to modify the dataframe (after attempting to import) yields this:

```
  File "<ipython-input-56-e6fa18118137>", line 1, in <module>
df = pd.read_excel(report())

  File "..\excel.py", line 151, in read_excel
return ExcelFile(io, engine=engine).parse(sheetname=sheetname, **kwds)

  File "..\excel.py", line 196, in __init__
raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'

ValueError: Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io.
```

Couldn't dig up much on that. I'm not even sure if I need to define a function.

- Do I import into a Pandas DataFrame directly from the function? Or
  keep it separate?
- How would I go about setting the engine?

Comment: I think your issue is with your date function. You're report function returns a None value (I think) since `datetime.datetime.today()` and `.fromtimestamp()` returns times to the millisecond. You want to add `.date()` to your timestamps. e.g. `datetime.datetime.today().date()` if you want it to be today. Unless of course you expect to run the code the very same millisecond the excel file was created.

Comment: You also need to have if `datetime.datetime.today() == xmod:` indented and additional time since that would be part of the `for x ... ` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, use `datetime.today().date()`. This will ensure the correct comparison format with `xmod`.

Second, that `glob` loop is kind of confusing. Are you sure you want the `for` and `if` to be in the same indentation level? Or should the `if` be inside the `for` loop? Either way, that needs to be fixed.

Also, try not passing in a function. Explicitly pass either a path or a buffer, as the error implies. Otherwise, it will ask you which engine to use, which is more work than it's worth for what you're doing.

All else, just subscribe to best programming/Python practices.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
    ...: from datetime import datetime
    ...: import os

In [2]: def load_if_modified_today(xls):
   ...:     modx = os.path.getmtime(xls)
   ...:     xmod = datetime.fromtimestamp(modx)
   ...:     if datetime.today().date() == xmod.date():
   ...:         df = pd.read_excel(xls)
   ...:         return df

In [3]: e = 'trades.xlsx'
   ...: df = load_if_modified_today(e)
   ...: df.head()
Out[3]: 
           System Name  Symbol  Unit Position Entry Date Entry Time  \
0  TB Turtle FX Majors  EURUSD     1    Short 2014-12-02        Day   
1  TB Turtle FX Majors  EURUSD     1    Short 2014-12-05        Day   
2  TB Turtle FX Majors  EURUSD     1     Long 2014-12-10        Day   
3  TB Turtle FX Majors  EURUSD     1     Long 2014-12-16        Day   
4  TB Turtle FX Majors  EURUSD     1    Short 2014-12-17        Day   

   Entry Order Price  Stop Price   Risk%  Quantity  Entry Fill  
0             1.2420      1.2428  0.0024         6      1.2418  
1             1.2284      1.2297  0.0022         4      1.2283  
2             1.2447      1.2434  0.0017         3      1.2448  
3             1.2496      1.2486  0.0026         5      1.2499  
4             1.2385      1.2397  0.0022         4      1.2383
```

Comment: Would I be able to use the glob module to load the file names beforehand? This would be something I'd run on a daily basis; would I have to input the name of the file (like your e variable as shown above) each time?

Comment: Edit: Got it figured out. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I came across same ValueError: Must explicitly set engine if not passing in buffer or path for io. After I altered my code to:

```
data = pd.read_excel(R"D:\\file.xlsx")
```

It worked.

Answer (score -1):

I ran across a similar issue, and it turned out that different python frame versions installed were conflicting each other. I removed one of them (anaconda), kept and updated plain python2.7 and all was fixed.